# Drupal 7 RSS feeds download instead of opening

Tags: drupal, rss

I've upgraded to Drupal 7 (from Drupal 6) and I'm having troubles with the RSS feeds. **The browser now prompts to download rss.xml**.

I've also noticed that Google Webmaster tools can't recognise the new rss.xml.

The header of rss.xml is:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 04 Jan 2012 12:42:54 GMT
Server: Apache
Expires: Sun, 19 Nov 1978 05:00:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
ETag: "1325680974"
Content-Language: pt
Last-Modified: Wed, 04 Jan 2012 12:42:54 GMT
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: application/rss+xml; charset=utf-8
```

I'm using Drupal core 7.10 and the plugin Comment RSS 7.x-2.3

sitemap.xml works and it's viewable by the browser.

Comment: Ok, so the problem was solved by removing the CRSS plugin. Still that forces me to stop having RSS feeds for comments.

Comment: For anyone else struggling with this issue, it appears Firefox will do this on malformed rss feeds.  I stumbled across this question while debugging a similar problem with my own feed. Plug your feed url into http://validator.w3.org/appc/  It doesn't need to be completely perfect though.  Fixed mine by adding a version attribute to the rss tag.